Update existing rule group of the network firewall of aws using terraform
I have two seperate and different terraform codes the first repo is used to create a network firewall with a policy attached to it using this code :
resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy" "NFPolicy" {
  name = "NFPolicy"

  firewall_policy {
    stateless_default_actions           = ["aws:forward_to_sfe"]
    stateless_fragment_default_actions  = ["aws:forward_to_sfe"]
    # Ajouter des Managed Rule Groups
    stateful_rule_group_reference {
      resource_arn = "arn:aws:network-firewall:eu-west-2:aws-managed:stateful-rulegroup/AbusedLegitBotNetCommandAndControlDomainsActionOrder"
    }
    stateful_rule_group_reference {
      resource_arn = "arn:aws:network-firewall:eu-west-2:aws-managed:stateful-rulegroup/AbusedLegitMalwareDomainsActionOrder"
    }
    stateful_rule_group_reference {
      resource_arn = "arn:aws:network-firewall:eu-west-2:aws-managed:stateful-rulegroup/BotNetCommandAndControlDomainsActionOrder"
    }
    stateful_rule_group_reference {
      resource_arn = "arn:aws:network-firewall:eu-west-2:aws-managed:stateful-rulegroup/MalwareDomainsActionOrder"
    }
  }
}


resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall" "NetworkFirewall" {
  name                 = "NetworkFirewall"
  vpc_id               = aws_vpc.NFINspection.id
  firewall_policy_arn  = aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy.NFPolicy.arn
  delete_protection    = false
  firewall_policy_change_protection = false
  subnet_change_protection = false

  subnet_mapping {
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.NFSubnetVPCNF.id
  }
}

Now in the second repo i want to only manage stateful rule groups and attach them to the policy already exist using terraform code but when i try to fulffil this stask using this code it show me an errors i don't know how to do it ?
The code used to create both stateful rule groups and update the policy
data "aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy" "existing_policy" {
  name = "NFPolicy"
}

resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy" "update_policy" {
  name = "NFPolicy"

  firewall_policy {
    stateless_default_actions          = data.aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy.existing_policy.firewall_policy.stateless_default_actions
    stateless_fragment_default_actions = data.aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy.existing_policy.firewall_policy.stateless_fragment_default_actions

    dynamic "stateful_rule_group_reference" {
      for_each = data.aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy.existing_policy.firewall_policy.stateful_rule_group_references
      content {
        resource_arn = stateful_rule_group_reference.value.resource_arn
      }
    }

    # Ajouter les nouveaux groupes de règles
    stateful_rule_group_reference {
      resource_arn = aws_networkfirewall_rule_group.allow_icmp.arn
    }

    stateful_rule_group_reference {
      resource_arn = aws_networkfirewall_rule_group.nwf_drop_tls_1_0_and_1_1.arn
    }
  }
}

When i try this to update the network firewall policy using the code before i get this errors
│ Error: Unknown variable
│
│   on network_firewall_policy.tf line 9, in resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy" "update_policy":
│    9:       for_each = data.aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy.existing_policy.firewall_policy.stateful_rule_group_references
│
│ There is no variable named "data".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on network_firewall_policy.tf line 9, in resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy" "update_policy":
│    9:       for_each = data.aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy.existing_policy.firewall_policy.stateful_rule_group_references
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access an
│ attribute for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the
│ list?


